# How to block a specific SQL query in postgres database?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.4

We have a development environment where the database (POSTGRESQL) is hosted.

The DB Admin's intention is to provide developers with `SELECT` permissions only on the respective target database and that is successfully implemented.

Here's the problem, the developers are able to access the full data, e.g. with `(SELECT * FROM TABLENAME / SELECT ID, NAME FROM TABLENAME)` through server-side scripts (hapiJS).

Since a custom api is being built, the developer can access the full table data through any browser in JSON format and that should be prevented someway.
Therefore my question is, is there a way to block a specific query such as `(SELECT * FROM TABLENAME)` in a POSTGRESQL DB?

Comment: You should block that in the webapp server, where the query is built. The database cannot know if the query is a legitimate query from the app server, or a pass-thru query from the user. Only the app server knows the difference, and must validate queries from the user, where such validation truly belongs.

Comment: Hi Andreas, thanks a lot for the post. As i am new bee in this feild, could you please be specific by providing some examples or article links to support your statement.

Comment: You need to look into [row level security](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-rowsecurity.html)

Comment: You could assign different account to each API key (or set of keys) and just use the same permissions you already have in place.